# Creating a social app with games with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know that there are some games created with MonoGame out there. I wonder if its possible to create a Xamarin.Forms app which has some games in it. More specifically, is it possible to start an OpenGL game when the user taps a Xamarin.Forms button for example? This is possible in native iOS games so it should be possible in Xamarin but I couldn't find any info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this question is downvoted.

- In Xamarin.Forms you can use `OpenGLView` which you can use as any other Forms view (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.OpenGLView/). Please note that it only works on iOS and Android.
- Mixing Forms and Native (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native). With this approach you can have native games.